# Hyperlinks do not auto updates from namedranges Excel 2013

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-2013

Why hyperlink do not update it values on Language change from named ranges?
How to fix that whithout vba?

[xlsx File attached](https://www.sendspace.com/file/xnd04j)

Try to change Language in B1 and look at links on mouse over, changing only "more" named range.
Now try to copy/paste formulas in others cells and change language again, everething works now, until file is open.

Comment: The hyperlinks in `F2:F5` and `F8:F9` are statically applied with `Insert - Hyperlink`. So the `HYPERLINK` function has no effect. Only in `F6:F7` it takes effect since there nothing is applied with `Insert - Hyperlink`.  So delete the static applied hyperlinks and it will work.

Comment: how to identify where is static and where is dinamic? All hyperlink was inserted manually and become static after some time automatically!!!

Comment: Right click on the cell. `F2` for example. If the options `Open Hyperlink` and `Edit Hyperlink` are in the context menu, then there is a static hyperlink applied. Select `Remove Hyperlink`. Now the `HYPERLINK` function takes effect.

Comment: Thanks man !!! Write the answer i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperlinks which are statically applied with `Insert - Hyperlink` are taking effect over the hyperlink target which results of the function `HYPERLINK`. So if there is a cell with such a static hyperlink applied and you write a `=HYPERLINK(...)` into that cell, then the static hyperlink target will take effect and *not* the hyperlink target of the `=HYPERLINK(...)`.

To repair this, right click on the cell. If the options `Open Hyperlink` and `Edit Hyperlink` are in the context menu, then there is a static hyperlink applied. Select `Remove Hyperlink` . Now the hyperlink target from the `HYPERLINK` function takes effect.